Catmull-Rom spline for Data visualization
So I am doing a project wehere we use the Convex hull to group the points and Catmull-Rom spline to make it more round like shown on the picture:

Now i got the next task which is to connect the paths that can be seen under to the convex hull so that i would look something like this:

So Im not sure how to go about this, i want to create paths that connect the circles like in bubblests, these kind of curvy paths, but im not sure at what math i should look at, and i would like to make my own and not just use a library that implements it, i've looked at following:\
https://github.com/MultiSetVis/MultiSetVis.github.io - sepcificly the simple scatterplot example.
https://bubblesets-js.josuakrause.com/
But im still not sure how they've done this, so if anyone has any idea im all ears.

I'm not sure I understand your question: your example of "connect[ing] the paths that can be seen under to the convex hull" doesn't show a connected path under the filled shape you show in the first picture. Could I ask you to make new pictures that are explicitly tailored to show off what you have, and what solution you want to get to, with a bit more of a description of what folks are looking at?

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Hey, i've seen your comment and i think i maybe have corrected the question as you asked me to. If anything please comment again or dm me if thats possible here. :)

You're still showing two things that seem completely different: can you keep the original picture as a 10% underlay or the like, so we can see exactly which points get this additional treatment? Because I can't tell where in picture 1 the points from picture 2 are.

The second link you posted is actually a JavaScript library (install with npm i bubblesets).
Then, you can get an outline like this:
import {
  BSplineShapeGenerator,
  BubbleSet,
  PointPath,
  ShapeSimplifier,
} from 'bubblesets';

const pad = 3;
const bubbles = new BubbleSet();
const rectanglesToInclude = [
  { x: 30, y: 40, width: 10, height: 20 },
  { x: 60, y: 30, width: 20, height: 10 },
  { x: 50, y: 50, width: 10, height: 10 },
];
const linesBetweenRectangles = [
  { x1: 35, x2: 70, y1: 50, y2: 35 },
  { x1: 70, x2: 55, y1: 35, y2: 55 },
];
const rectanglesToAvoid = [
  { x: 40, y: 20, width: 10, height: 10 },
  { x: 30, y: 60, width: 10, height: 20 },
  { x: 30, y: 50, width: 20, height: 20 },
];
const outlineList = bubbles.createOutline(
  BubbleSet.addPadding(rectanglesToInclude, pad),
  BubbleSet.addPadding(rectanglesToAvoid, pad),
  linesBetweenRectangles,
);
// outline is a path that can be used for the attribute d of a SVG path element
const outline = new PointPath(outlineList).transform([
  new ShapeSimplifier(0.0),  // removes path points by removing (near) co-linear points
  new BSplineShapeGenerator(),  // smoothes the output shape using b-splines
  new ShapeSimplifier(0.0),  // removes path points by removing (near) co-linear points
]);
const svgPath = document.getElementById('mypath');
svgPath.setAttribute('d', `${outline}`);

where the HTML would be something like:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script async src="index.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
<svg>
  <path id="mypath" fill="#e41a1c" stroke="black"></path>
</svg>
</body>
</html>

BubbleSets works by creating a potential field of the full bounding box of all elements. The potential is roughly defined by the distance to the closest element to include penalized by the distance to elements to exclude. The initial outline is created by walking along the field where the potential has a certain threshold value. This result is stored in outlineList as simply array of control points. This initial outline is typically quite rugged, noisy, and has many redundant points. For this we convert the list into a PointPath which is a wrapper to easily manipulate the points via the transform function. We apply two transformations: removing co-linear points to get rid of redundant points and smoothing the curve via BSplines. You can see the implementation of the BSpline simplifier here: https://github.com/JosuaKrause/bubblesets-js/blob/58cb0d5b3d4962810635019e9d917d0b65f7c076/bubblesets.js#L2467-L2561
You were asking about Catmull-Rom splines. They are not implemented for the JavaScript version but you can see an implementation in the Java version: https://github.com/JosuaKrause/Bubble-Sets/blob/41c3218491e9e7b38b69c978fe9afd2bd21e7a65/src/main/java/setvis/shape/CardinalSplineGenerator.java
The transformation approach is the same for both the Java and the JavaScript version so it should be relatively straight-forward to transfer over the implementation.
